# how to clean POST and GET vars in PHP for XSS and SQL injection

Tags: php, http-post, xss, http-get

In my web app is a config file which includes i.e. database connection settings ans is always loaded at the first line of a PHP script. I would like to include a function which cleans all POST and GET data for maybe existing XSS and SQL Injection risks.

I am not sure if that function is really enough

```
function make_safe($variable) 
{
   $variable = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($variable)));
   return $variable; 
}

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
   $_POST[$key] = make_safe($value);
}
//Same for $_GET & $_SESSION
```

Do you have recommendation for this problem?

Comment: You have two different problems here. Focus on them one at a time. Deal with SQL injection when inserting data into SQL. Deal with XSS when inserting data into HTML.

Comment: [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) is a duplicate of the *first* problem you have (SQL injection). XSS is your second problem. There are plenty of answers explaining how to defend against that too, search around for them.

Comment: If you use above mentioned function, then will you be able to use editors in your app?

Answer (score 4):

This function:

```
function make_safe($variable) 
{
   $variable = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($variable)));
   return $variable; 
}
```

Will not work

SQL injection and XSS are two different beasts. Because they each require different escaping you need to use each escape function strip_tags and mysql_real_escape_string separatly.
Joining them up will defeat the security of each.

Use the standard mysql_real_escape_string() when inputting data into the database.
Use strip_tags() when querying stuff out of the database before outputting them to the screen.

Why combining the two function is dangerous
From the horses mouth: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Because `strip_tags()` does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.

So by inputting malformed html into a database field a smart attacker can use your naive implementation to defeat `mysql_real_escape_string()` in your combo.

Comment: Don't use mysql_real_escape_string. Stop using the obsolete mysql extension entirely and use PDO or mysqli.